# How insert in to two table with same auto increment id

Tags: mysql, database

I need to insert data from a flat_table into two tables client_data client_contact.

```
flat_table
    f_name
    l_name
    client_id
    phone
    address

client_data
    id AI
    f_name
    l_name
    ...
    ... 

client_contact
    client_id
    phone
    address
    ...
    ...
```

I was thinking of using mysql_last_id somehow but I don't know even where to start.

there are other questions like this but they don't answer my question.

Comment: On your second insert you can use [last_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) for the foreign key column. (Given that you insert your data row by row.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming that no two clients share the same `f_name` and `l_name`:

   ```
   INSERT INTO client_data (f_name, l_name)
     SELECT DISTINCT f_name, l_name
     FROM   flat_table;

   INSERT INTO client_contact (client_id, phone, address)
     SELECT d.id, f.phone, f.address
     FROM   flat_table f JOIN client_data d USING (f_name, l_name);
   ```
2. Assuming that all records in `flat_table` correspond to a different client:

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE flat_table2 (
     id SERIAL
   ) SELECT * FROM flat_table;

   INSERT INTO client_data (id, f_name, l_name)
     SELECT DISTINCT id, f_name, l_name
     FROM   flat_table2;

   INSERT INTO client_contact (client_id, phone, address)
     SELECT id, phone, address
     FROM   flat_table2;

   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE flat_table2;
   ```
3. If different clients may share the same `f_name` and `l_name` but not every record in `flat_table` corresponds to a unique client, you will need to find some way of identifying which records correspond with which clients.

Comment: what if two people have the same name? ie "John Smith"

Comment: i think i got it. i will use both. create a temp table with and id then use your first example but the id as the join. Thanks.